# Is it possible to assign the EHCI-PCI driver to a single laptop USB port?

Tags: ipod, xhci-hcd

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 XFCE.

I have an iPod shuffle (second generation) running on my old laptop I noticed that the old laptop USB ports are assigned to the EHCI-PCI driver, while into the new portable, the ipod is not detected, and all USB ports are assigned to the driver xhci_hcd.

Would it be possible to assign into the new laptop, one USB port (not all, only one USB port ) to the EHCI-PCI driver?

Thanks.